# Tengo la aplicación de escritorio y la base de datos de Java en Hostinger, se mueve lento en todo

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio desarrollada en java, su base de datos está en un host (Hostinger), el problema es el siguiente: una vez que inicio sesión en la aplicación, cuando voy a insertar o modificar un registro en la base de datos, se necesita un mucho tiempo para llevar a cabo ese proceso.

Además, cuando abro el formulario JDialog, lleva tiempo abrirse, a diferencia de cuando lo uso localmente.

Yo uso conector -> mysql-connector-java-8.0.24

Tengo una buena conexión a internet

Esta es mi clase de conexión

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Conexion {

    // Conexion
  
      public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://Hostname:port/DatabaseName?useCompresion=true&autoReconnet=true&useSSL=false";
      public static final String usuario = "User";
      public static final String contraseña = "Password"; 

      public Connection getConection(){
          Connection conexion = null;
          
          try{
              Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
              conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,usuario,contraseña);
              //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conexion Exitosa");
              
           }catch(Exception ex){
               
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Conexion a la Base de Datos "+ex);
               
           }
      
          
          return conexion;
          
      }

}
```

Comment: Por casualidad ¿Creas una conexión cada vez que insertas o modificas un registro?

Comment: Llamo a mi Clase Conexión e instancio un objeto de ella.    ` Conexion con = new Conexion();
            Connection conexion = con.getConection();
            ps = conexion.prepareStatement("query aqui")`

Comment: Cada autenticación a la base de datos te cuesta unos segundos, por eso deberías evitarla por cada transacción. La idea de implementar un *singleton* es precisamente crear una conexión al arrancar la aplicación, y reusarla para cada transacción, y al cerrar la aplicación, cerrar también la conexión.

Comment: Estuve implementando el Singleton en todo el proyecto y el resultado es muy favorable me funciona a la perfeción. Gracias por tu ayuda.    Saludos!